# Guitar Rig on Ubuntu with WINE, i/o not working

Tags: ubuntu, audio, asio, winetricks, jackd

I'm trying to run Guitar Rig on Ubuntu with WINE using a Scarlett Focusrite 2i2 but can't seem to get the input signal to register. I've set up WINEASIO and jack and everything appears to be fine, but when I plug in, the input meter doesn't budge.

When I open up my system settings, I can see the level works fine, but when I try to test my audio output I hear nothing. Incidentally, vlc plays audio just fine, so I'm pretty confused.

Additionally, as expected, lspci, aplay and arecord all show the device registered, but it's device 1, not device 0. I tried changing my jack config to use hw:1 instead of hw:0, but then it just crashed.

Any thoughts or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't use Linux for ASIO, but in a windows environment, VLC would be using the windows subsystem which is "distinct" from ASIO, so not diagnostic. I suspect the problem lies in the connection between Jack and WineASIO. It may help to include more detail for how GR is configured, since the path ( Windows GR > wineasio > jack > focusrite ) has several points of failure. Also, I recent search hits suggest some potential difficulties with version compat between  wineasio and jack

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. Fixed my. jackdrc using qjackctl and changed the device from default (previously hw:0) to my interface hw:USB). Then I killed at the jack processes (killall jackdbus jackd), started up qjackctl and then guitar rig. Presto